# Insert and Delete at Head and Tail of Linked List in constant time

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am trying to write a Linked List implementation that can insert and delete at either head or tail in constant time.

I think I have it working, but I was curious what improvements I could make to this code?

Additionally, is there a way to delete from the tail in constant time without having a doubly linked list?

```
public class LinkedList {

    private ListNode head;
    private ListNode tail;
    private int size;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void insert(int index, int data) {
        if (index > size) { throw new System.ArgumentException("Index is larger than size of list"); }
        if (index == 0) {
            ListNode node = new ListNode(data, head, null);
            if (head == null) {
                tail = node;
            }
            else {
                head.Prev = node;
            }
            head = node;
        }
        else if ( index == size) {
            ListNode node = new ListNode(data, tail.Prev, tail);
            tail.Next = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        else {
            ListNode currNode = _find(index);
            ListNode node = new ListNode(data, currNode, currNode.Prev);
            currNode.Prev.Next = node;
            currNode.Prev = node;
        }

        size++;
    }

    public void delete(int index) {
        if (index > size - 1) { throw new System.ArgumentException("Index is larger than size of list"); }
        if (index == 0) {
            head = head.Next;
            head.Prev = null;
        }
        else if (index == size - 1) {
            tail = tail.Prev;
            tail.Next = null;
        }
        else {
            ListNode node = _find(index);
            node.Prev.Next = node.Next;
            node.Next.Prev = node.Prev;
        }
        size--;
    }

    private ListNode _find(int index) {
        ListNode currNode = head;
        for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
            currNode = currNode.Next;
        }
        return currNode;
    }

    public int this[int key] {
        get { return _find(key).Data; }
        set { _find(key).Data = value; }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

}

internal class ListNode {

    private int data;
    private ListNode next;
    private ListNode prev;

    public ListNode(int data, ListNode link, ListNode prev) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = link;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public int Data { get => data; set => data = value; }
    public ListNode Next { get => next; set => next = value; }
    internal ListNode Prev { get => prev; set => prev = value; }
}
```

Unit Test Code

```
using Fundamentals;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTests {
[TestFixture]
public class LinkedListUnitTests {

    LinkedList LList;

    [SetUp]
    public void init() {
        LList = new LinkedList();
    }

    [Test]
    public void canAccessSizeOfLinkedList() {
        Assert.That(LList.getSize(), Is.EqualTo(0));
    }

    [Test]
    public void canInsertAtBeginningOfLinkedList() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);
        Assert.That(LList[0], Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void canInsertAtEndOfLinkedList() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);

        LList.insert(1, 2);
        Assert.That(LList[LList.getSize() - 1], Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void canInsertIntoMiddleOfLinkedList() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);
        LList.insert(1, 3);

        LList.insert(1, 2);
        Assert.That(LList[1], Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void canAccessWithBrackets() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);
        LList.insert(1, 2);
        LList.insert(2, 3);
        Assert.That(LList[1], Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void canSetWithBrackets() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);
        LList.insert(1, 2);
        LList.insert(2, 4);
        LList[2] = 3;
        Assert.That(LList[2], Is.EqualTo(3));
    }

    [Test]
    public void canDeleteFromEndOfLinkedList() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);
        LList.insert(1, 2);
        LList.insert(2, 3);
        LList.delete(2);
        Assert.That(LList.getSize(), Is.EqualTo(2));
        //TODO check that the end was actually deleted
    }

    [Test]
    public void canDeleteFromBeginningofLinkedList() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);
        LList.insert(1, 2);
        LList.insert(2, 3);
        LList.delete(0);
        Assert.That(LList.getSize(), Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(LList[0], Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void canDeleteFromMiddleOfLinkedList() {
        LList.insert(0, 1);
        LList.insert(1, 2);
        LList.insert(2, 3);
        LList.delete(1);
        Assert.That(LList.getSize(), Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(LList[1], Is.EqualTo(3));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: To delete from one of the ends of a linked list in constant time, you need to be able to find the next or previous node in constant time. This isn't possible in a singly linked list for both head and tail. However, you never mention whether random insertion/deletion time complexity is important to you. If it isn't, you could take a look at circular buffers (aka "ring buffers").

Comment: @hoffmale, that comment sounds like a great start to a wonderful review.

Comment: @hoffmale I am going in hell for this, isn't this doubly linked list... he has "pointers" to both prev and next? Or I am missing something

Comment: @kuskmen: Read OP's third sentence, he especially asks about removing the tail in constant time without having to use a doubly linked list (which I took to mean using a singly linked list). I chose that formulation, because it's trivial to make a reverse linked list (tail pointer + prev pointers instead of head and next) and I wanted to be general. If this is about circular buffers, they don't have pointers in that sense at all, they're just a special kind of array whose indices wrap around.

Answer (score 1):

## Properties

The properties in `ListNode` can be simplified to:

```
public int Data { get; set; }
public ListNode Next { get; set; }
internal ListNode Prev { get; set; }
```

Similarly, `size` and `getSize` in `LinkedList` can be refactored into a property:

```
public int Size { get; private set; }
```

## Runtime complexity

Traversal of a linked list has time complexity \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$. So to provide \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ insertion and deletion at both `head` and `tail` requires a method to look up the next or previous node in \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ time, respectively.

To illustrate:

Let's say you have a forward singly linked list. To remove the `tail` node, you need to find it, which usually takes \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time.

A naive idea for improvement would be to take a reference to the node before `tail` and store it, so it (or `tail` through it) can be accessed in constant time.

Using this idea, tail insertion can be reduced to \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ time complexity:

```
// pseudo code
void InsertAtTail(T value) {
   var tail = beforeTail.Next;
   tail.Next = new ListNode(value);
   beforeTail = tail;
}
```

Good so far. But what about deletion? One could try:

```
void DeleteTail() {
    // delete tail, easy!
    beforeTail.Next = null;
    // uh oh, we need to update beforeTail...
    // so, find the node where node.Next == beforeTail
    for(var node = head; node != null; node = node.Next) {
        if(node.Next == beforeTail) {
            beforeTail = node;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, deletion takes \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, because `beforeTail` needs to be updated. Of course, the same idea can be extended to the node before `beforeTail`, but the end result would be the same.

(This argument applies the same way for deletion of head in a reverse singly linked list, i.e. a singly linked list build upon `tail` and `prev` references.)

So, what to use if you need \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ `head` and `tail` insertion?

The obvious answer is: Use a doubly linked list. And it works, because now `beforeTail` (from the example above) can now be updated in constant time!

But a doubly linked list brings much more to the table than required: It also has constant time random insertion/deletion (if you have a reference to the relevant node). If this isn't needed, there is also another data structure which can do constant time `head` and `tail` insertions/deletions: Circular buffers.

> Granted, if the buffer is dynamically sized (i.e. grows its space if required), the time complexity is only **amortized** \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$, but for a fixed size it is \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ withour amortization.
>
> As a bonus, the contents of the buffer are usually in a contiguous memory region, which can help performance on modern processors because it helps memory prefetching (for comparison: Linked lists with all their references chains are notoriously bad at this).

## Naming

In C#, `PascalCase` is usually preferred for `public` fields, properties and methods. Using this style, which is prevalent in the BCL, helps to better integrate your implementation with other code.

Of course, once you start implementing BCL interfaces on your types, another argument could be made for consistency, as those interfaces require `PascalCase` names.

## Class design

#### Enumerator

As mentioned above, a strong point for choosing a (*doubly*) linked list is constant time random insertion (*and deletion*). However, to get that time complexity, some form of reference to the relevant node needs to be handed out.

This is usually done by wrapping it inside a `LinkedListEnumerator`. Doing this allows for:

- Easy list iteration (e.g. in a `foreach` loop or using LINQ)
- Passing references to the outside of the `LinkedList` without breaking encapsulation (so it's still the implementation that controls the lists behavior).
- Allow external code to keep references to a specific node **even when the list has been changed**.

  To elaborate: The current implementation uses `int` indices to lookup values inside the list. Let's say a value `x`  we care about is at index `idx`. If some code now inserts or deletes an element from the list, `x` might not be at index `idx` anymore. So in order to keep track of `x`, we need a more direct reference to the node, which the `LinkedListEnumerator` provides.

#### Other design issues

- The `LinkedList` class could easily be made generic so it could contain other values than just `int`s.
- Some utility functions would be nice, like `Sort` or `Find`. Currently, there is not easy way to interact with elements inside the list (though the enumerator solution above would fix this at least somewhat).